# Is typedef inside of a function body a bad programming practice?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have some class `C` and want to pass address of its instance and method to some functor in  a test function `Test_C_Foo1()`. Functor is a template class and I have to provide type of the class method (`MEMFN1`) as one of its template parameters. I have to define `MEMFN1` type somewhere but don't want to change `C.h` and don't want to pollute global namespace with it. I decided to localize *typedef* as much as possible so put it inside a test-function - within the scope where `MEMFN1` is actually used. **Is using a typedef inside the function body a good practice?**

Standard allows using *typedef* inside a function body, restricting it only in these particular cases:

> The typedef specifier shall not be combined in a decl-specifier-seq
>   with any other kind of specifier except a type-specifier, and it shall
>   not be used in the decl-specifier-seq of a parameter-declaration
>   (8.3.5) nor in the decl-specifier-seq of a function-definition (8.4).

Here's the code snippet:

**C.h:**

```
...
#include <string>
...

class C
{
public:
    int foo1(const std::string&);       
};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
...
#include "C.h"
...

void Test_C_Foo1()
{
   typedef int(C::*MEMFN1)(const std::string&);

   C c;   
   Functor1<C, MEMFN1,...> f1(&c, &C1::foo1,...);
   ...
}

...

int main()
{
    Test_C_Foo1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guys, thank you for your answers. Narrowing the scope of *typedef* in this case seemed natural choice to me and I had doubt only because I couldn't remember if I've ever came across it in the code or literature.

Comment: Could you use `decltype` with C++11?

Comment: @PeterWood I am limited to C++03 but thank you for this suggestion. I didn't know about this new feature and just had a brief look at its description. Would this be correct (and enough) in C++11? `Functor1<C, decltype(&C::foo1),...> f1(&c, &C1::foo1,...);`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's *good*. It's legal and localized.

Comment: It is more than good: it is sometimes *necessary*. Think of `typedef` as a kind of "type variable assignment".

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, if the `typedef` is just to avoid typing or to make the pointer-to-member-function less cumbersome, as your example shows, thenit is fine.

But if the `typedef` reveals some particular concept, then it should be visible outside of the function.

A quick test to check it is the name of the `typedef`:

```
typedef int(C::*MEMFN1)(const std::string&); //OK: as local typedef, just an abbreviation

typedef int(C::*ACTION)(const std::string&); //Not so OK: Action is a new concept
```

Comment: You're saying that if a name means something, then it should be global? That's rather an odd viewpoint.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - Well, that is a general guideline. And not global exactly, but visible next to the other concepts it complements. For example if the `ACTION` typedef were meaningful, it should be defined next to the `C` class.

Comment: why downvote this, chaps? everyone offended over programming philosophy, again? :) ..there's an IMHO there even, and this sounds worth being here, ..IMHO :))