# Can I use C++20 concepts properly in a using declaration?

Tags: c++, clang++, c++20, c++-concepts

I was playing around a bit with Concepts offered in C++20 and came up with a simple example, which, to my surprise, [does not produce the expected results](https://godbolt.org/z/tDd92q) (please leave any discussion on the usefulness of my example be :-)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept i_am_integral = requires { std::is_integral_v<T> == true; };

template <typename T> requires i_am_integral<T>
using intvector = std::vector<T>;

int main() {
    intvector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 }; // <- This is fine, int is an integral type

    // I would expect this to fail:
    intvector<double> w = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };

    // I'm curious, so let's print the vector
    for (auto x : w) { std::cout << x << '\n'; }

    // Same here - IMO, this should fail:
    struct S{};
    intvector<S> s;
}
```

I tried to make `intvector` a "restricted" `std::vector` which is only allowed to take integral types. However, `intvector` seems to swallow arbitrary types just like the original vector, including user defined types.

Is this my fault or is clang not yet stable enough to handle this case properly? I suspect there is an issue in mixing type aliases and requirements (as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365653/1753435)), but I am unable to grasp it - in particular, my example compiles, while the one in the referenced post doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept i_am_integral = requires { std::is_integral_v<T> == true; };
```

does not check if the type is integral. Instead, it checks if comparing `std::is_integral_v<T>` with `true` is possible (which is always possible). To fix your code you should just do:

```
template <typename T>
concept i_am_integral = std::is_integral_v<T>;
```